# Exception in thread "main" while formatting namenode in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

```
satya@ubuntu:~/hadoop/bin$ hadoop namenode -format
```

> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 3):

This error (`Unsupported major.minor version`) generally appears because of using a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime. In this case `51` corresponds to JDK 7 (for more version mappings visit [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)), this indicates that
whatever the JVM 1.6 runtime loaded, it was meant for JVM 1.7. Try using JDK 1.7 and set that using `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in `hadoop-env.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

The default java version and you Hadoop's java version should match. Do this:

```
java -version
```

Open `hadoop-env.sh` (can be found in hadoop config folder) and search for `JAVA_HOME`. This java version and the default java version should match.

> **NOTE:** Set your JAVA_HOME to point to jdk folder and not your java's bin folder

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can show your Hadoop version... but for Hadoop 2, I think you can try the new format command

```
[hdfs]$ $HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format [-clusterid cid] [-force] [-nonInteractive]
```

So in your case, type

```
satya@ubuntu:~/hadoop/bin$ hdfs namenode -format
```

(I'm referring to [`Hadoop 2.7.0`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#namenode) which should apply to your situation.)

Answer (score 0):

I also met the question. And when I type:

```
$hadoop classpath
```

I find the classpath of hdfs is wrong. Then I did

```
vi ~/.bashrc 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```

It works, hope it helps.